# Python - Multiple while loops in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
while z[0] <= D(0):
  if z[1] >= z[0]:
    if Fractionate(1) > 0:

      while z[1] <= D(1):
        if z[2] >= z[1]:
          if Fractionate(2) > 0:

            while z[2] <= D(2):
              if z[3] >= z[2]:
                if Fractionate(3) > 0:
```

Here I have a bunch of while loops and they're all doing the same thing. I was wondering if i could use some sort of for loop to shorten this. I can't just do

```
for i in range(0, k - 2):
  while z[0] <= D(0):
    if z[i+1] >= z[i]:
      if Fractionate(i+1) > 0:
```

Because it only does 1 while loop at a time.

Comment: maybe use `continue`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but I would recommend using a recursive function, something like this:

```
def recurse(n):
    while z[n] <= D(n):
        if z[n+1] >= z[n]:
            if Fractionate(n+1) > 0:
                return recurse(n+1)
            else:
                return base value

recurse(0)
```

Comment: No problem, just remember to mark this as answered if it helped solve your problem!